# Can't push to Siteground or BitBucket because branch is behind - can't merge duo to unrelated histories

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to setup a git workflow with Siteground and BitBucket. This is how I wan't my workflow to be:

- I develop websites locally
- Occasionally I push to BitBucket for backup/version control.
- When done and ready for live, I'm pushing to the live site on Siteground.

Both Siteground and BitBucket are correctly setup, but I'm having trouble pushing to BitBucket and live.

If I try pushing to BitBucket or Siteground I get the error: *"Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart"*. So I figured, that I needed to merge the branches, but that didn't work because *"fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories".*

I'm using SourceTree as my GUI and I'm by no means a git pro. This is what it looks like:

[image]

How do I get this working?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've started 3 unrelated repositories: i.e. none of the changes in Siteground, Bitbucket or your local repository look related. NOtice how the commit log shows 3 disjoint segments.

First, you need to figure out which one of those repositories you want to use, and if there is any content in the other repositories you want to keep.

Once you have decided that, checkout that branch, use `git cherry-pick` to copy over those changes, and finally use `git push --force` to push that version to both bitbucket and siteground.

MAKE SURE YOU HAVE BACKUPS OF ALL COPIES LOCALLY.